# CSS table nthchild() last td is not showing the border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-tables

I m trying to show the table td's as one with the border and one without the border on the bottom. All works but when it comes to the last td of the table, border-bottom is not working.

Moreover it's not working in IE at all:

```
.moduletablehome table tbody tr td:nth-child(odd) {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.moduletablehome table tbody tr td:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle link: [jsfiddle.net/EC6dW/2](http://jsfiddle.net/EC6dW/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I got the solution,

I have given the border-bottom dashed to tr

and removed the border-bottom from both the td's

Answer (score 1):

To make this work with IE you will need to use Javascript/JQuery.

Here is a quick tutorial http://verboselogging.com/2010/01/17/making-nth-child-work-everywhere

Comment: Hi Casey, I m looking to fix it by css and html only.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to show the table td's as one with the border and one without the border on the bottom.

Your code specifies the bottom border for both cases, so I'm not sure if that's what you want?  As you have it, the difference between the odd and even cases is in `border-right`, so perhaps you meant to switch around `border-bottom` and `border-right`?.

I cleaned up your jsfiddle to what I thought was the minimum necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/EC6dW/5/ and saw what I expected from your css.  (I changed the even tds to use `border-bottom: 1px dotted` like in your question instead of `1px solid` as you had in the jsfiddle).

Comment: border-bottom is available in all, but border right is required to be in left td only. and for some reason that border-bottom is not showing in the last td